# Proof the following corollary of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For any $ f \in M^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ (measurable positive functions), the function $$\lambda: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
\mathcal{A} \text{ is the set of measurable funtions}$$

given by $ \lambda(E) = \int_{E}f $ is a measure.

I already proved:

i) $\lambda(\emptyset) = \int_{\emptyset}f = 0$

ii) let $A \subseteq B \in \mathcal{A}$ then $$f|_A \le f|_B$$'
so $$ \int f|_A \le \int f|_B  $$ that is $$ \lambda(A) = \int_Af=\int f|_A = \int fX_A  \le \int fX_B = \int f|_B = \int_B f = \lambda(B)$$

Now I am stuck in sigma additivity

iii) let $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ so $ \lambda(A\cup B) = \lambda(A) +\lambda(B) $ if the sets are disjoint then I think I can do it, but can we do that assumption?  any help to prove this?

Comment: Of course the sets are disjoint. But you need to consider countably many disjoint sets, not just two.

Comment: I see.. so is more complicated that I expect...

Comment: The characteristic function on a countable disjoint union is the sum of the characteristic functions on each of the set. So what you need to show is that the integral of an infinite sum is the sum of the integrals, under certain conditions.

Comment: I think that condtion is uniformly convergence... but I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Use the dominated convergence theorem 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

on

$f_N=f\chi_{A_N} \  \ $ where $ A_N=\bigcup_{i=0}^N E_i $

$\int f_N = \int f\chi_{A_N}=\int _{\bigcup_{i=0}^N E_i}f=\sum_{i=0}^N\int_{E_i}f$

check that it satisfies all the conditions when you take $g=f$

The theorem implies

$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_N=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^N\int_{E_i}f = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\int_{E_i}f = \int f$

Answer (score 1):

In general if $(f_n)_n$ denotes a sequence of measurable functions that all take values in $[0,\infty]$ then:

- Also $f:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is a properly defined measurable function that takes values in $[0,\infty]$.
- For every $n$ the integral $\int f_n$ is properly defined.
- Also the integral $\int f$ is properly defined and satisfies $\int f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n$.

This under the convention that for $a,b\in[0,\infty]$ we have $a+b:=\infty$ if $\infty\in\{a,b\}$.

Concerning the third bullet we have $f\geq\sum_{n=1}^mf_n$ and consequently $\int f\geq\int\sum_{n=1}^mf_n=\sum_{n=1}^m\int f_n$ for every $m$ so that $\int f\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n$.

Conversely the lemma of Fatou can be used: $$\int f=\int\liminf_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^mf_n\leq\liminf_{m\to\infty}\int\sum_{n=1}^mf_n=\liminf_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\int f_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n$$

---

Using this we find for measurable and disjoint sets $A_n$ that: $$\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\int f\mathbf1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n}=\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\mathbf1_{A_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f\mathbf1_{A_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda(A_n)$$